# При нажатии на img, он должен стать фоном блока div

Tags: javascript

Стоит задача при нажатии на любую из 4 картинок, чтобы они заменяли фон блока `div` собою... Класс у `img` одинаковый. Помогите доработать код, пожалуйста.

```js
var div = document.querySelector('#div');
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    img[i].onclick = function changeBgd () {
       var imgSrc = img[i].getAttribute('src')
       div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + imgSrc + ')';
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
<img class="img" src="img/html.png" alt="html">
<img class="img" src="img/css.png" alt="css">
<img class="img" src="img/js.png" alt="js">
<img class="img" src="img/php.png" alt="php">
```

Comment: прикольно... первый вопрос на stack overflow! Всегда только читал.

Comment: можно заменить везде `var` на [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let). Если в цикле использовать `var`, то он как-то криво работает, и после цикла значение переменной равно `img.length`, поэтому внутри функции обработчика `img[i] === undefined`. Возможно где-то есть каноничный ответ про это)

Comment: спасибо, за ответ я попробую ) Да ECMAScript 6 ждет (let,const...)! Но нужно по основам еще пройтись.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var div = document.querySelector('#div');
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
  img[i].onclick = function changeBgd() {
    div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + this.src + ')';
  }
}
```

```css
#div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 230px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.img {
  width: 101px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<img class="img" src="https://www.meteoprog.ua/pictures/news_v_2/cb2c2cd8ad03cf81f708fdbaaf7cea63.jpg" alt="html">
<img class="img" src="https://tumix.ru/media/cache/f0/3c/f03c326b3be08f9f2c85d3a248e0ae98.jpg" alt="css">
<img class="img" src="https://wallperz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/06/wallperz.com-20161106191020.jpg" alt="js">
<img class="img" src="http://www.2fons.ru/pic/201406/1920x1200/2fons.ru-17235.jpg" alt="php">
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: лови плюс, и пользуясь моментом,- ты хотел сделать пример анимации на css, и от меня  получить перевод его на smil svg

Comment: @Alexandr_T, да я помню, просто застрял тут с одной штукой на, сервере надо реализовать. А за двумя зайцами... Как говорится... закончу с сервером, потом займусь SVG...  Благодарю...

Comment: спасибо, помогли! не в ту сторону думал. а всё проще оказалось двигаюсь дальше, Надеюсь еще кому-то будет полезен вопрос.)

Comment: всегда пожалуйста....